# ORACLE calculate Sales، returns and the rest for a customer in the same table for the sam product

Tags: oracle, select

ORACLE select

calculate Sales، returns and the rest for a customer in the same table for the same product according to trans type 
 i need to calculate total sales and total returns and the rest for the customer and items.

and group by customer

Trans_Type:
1= Sales 
2= Return

```
    ID   Trans_Type   DATE         Items_ID     Quantity   Clint_ID
    ---  ----------   --------     ----------  ----------  ----------
    1          1      16-OCT-09      701555    3               1
    2          2      12-DEC-09      701555    1               1
    3          1      30-JUL-10      701511    63              2
    4          2      30-JUL-10      701555    1               1
    5          1      30-JUL-10      701234    2               3  
    6          1      30-JUL-10      701234    5               3
    7          2      30-JUL-10      701511    1               2
    8          1      30-JUL-10      701522    3               2
    9          1      30-JUL-10      701555    2               3
    10         1      30-JUL-10      701555    4               2 
    11         2      30-JUL-10      701555    2               2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood everything correct you need to use `case when ...` and `group by ...` clauses, like here:

```
select clint_id, items_id, qty, ret, nvl(qty,0) - nvl(ret,0) rest
  from (
    select clint_id, items_id, 
      sum(case when trans_type = 1 then quantity end) qty, 
      sum(case when trans_type = 2 then quantity end) ret 
    from data group by clint_id, items_id )
  order by clint_id, items_id
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8ea2/2)</sup>

Comment: ** Thank you**  i will give it a try in a while and reply to you the result..

`Thank you Again :)`

Comment: Glad I could help. Please read: [someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).